# jq: how to add elements from an array into another array one by one

Tags: arrays, json, jq

First array file1:

```
[{"1":"2"}, {"3":"4"}]
```

Second array in file2:

```
[{"a":"b"}, {"c":"d"}]
```

I tried "jq -s -c '.[0][] + .[1][]' file1 file2". The result:

```
{"1":"2","a":"b"}
{"3":"4","a":"b"}
{"1":"2","c":"d"}
{"3":"4","c":"d"}
```

However, I want the following:

```
{"1":"2","a":"b"}
{"3":"4","c":"d"}
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An (the?) elegant way:

```
$ jq -n --argfile f1 file1.json --argfile f2 file2.json -f program.jq
```

where program.jq is:

```
[$f1,$f2]
| transpose
| map(add)
```